# What's the difference between BSD-style and Unix-style command line options?

Tags: linux, unix, command-line-interface, freebsd

I tried to google it but to no avail. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the program.  `ps` is the one that you encounter the most often - somebody who grew up in a BSD environment will type `ps auwwx` while somebody who grew up in a System V environment will type `ps -ef` even though `ps` these days supports both types of options now.

Answer (score 2):

Much and little, see:

- http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/linux-users/article.html
- http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.xhtml

Also worry about:

Case sensitivity e.g.

```
mailx -R  replyTo@domain.com .....  # GNU/Linux
mailx -r  replyTo@domain.com .....  # Unix
```

Options required in some flavours but not others e.g.

```
/usr/bin/echo -e "This\nis a\n test"  # GNU/Linux
/bin/echo        "This\nis a\n test"  # Unix
```

Additional options e.g.

```
last -y  # BSD  - include year
last -a  # GNU/Linux - include hostname
```

Comment: See also (only allowed 2 links):  - http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/Unix/unixguide.php
 - http://www.amazon.co.uk/Linux-Command-Cross-Reference-ebook/dp/B0088A0XFQ

Answer (score 1):

One of the major differences across the platform is positional arguments.  Most of the command line utilities will enforce that flags come before positional arguments.  That is, on a GNU system, the following is fine:

```
ls / -la
```

On BSD, these are typically not valid.  Obviously, this isn't the extent of the differences between the two, but its one of the differences that drives me up the wall when I switch between them.